# Update ngForm controls on ngModelGroup update

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an `ngForm` with a static input (question), and then an `ngModelGroup` with a number of inputs (using `ngFor`), that the user can add or remove (answers). The answers are stored in an array. I have some validation on all these fields; required, min-length etc.

On submission of the form, I'm checking for any empty input fields in the answers array and removing them.  I am then checking that the form is valid and if so, submitting.

Simplified code:

HTML:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <div #answers="ngModelGroup" ngModelGroup="answers">
         <div *ngFor="let answer of answers; let idx = index; trackBy: trackByAnswers">
             <input type="text" name="answer{{idx}}" [(ngModel)]="poll.options[idx]" required minlength="1">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
form: NgForm;

this.answers = this.answers.filter(answer => {
    return answer !== '';
})

if (this.form.valid) {
    // submit
}
```

The issue is that when the code reaches `this.form.valid`. Say I have 3 answers, the last of which is an empty string. This gets removed by the filter, and so we're left with 2 answers. However, when the code reaches `this.form.valid` it still thinks there's 3 inputs.

I verified there's 2 inputs at validation by checking the DOM with `document.getElementsByClassName()`. If I log `form.controls` I can see that NgForm still thinks there's 3 inputs.

I've tried forcing Angular to detect the changes with `changeDetectionRef.detectChanges()`, `setTimeout` and `updateValueAndValidity()` but they don't work.

How can I make the form refresh to see there's only 2 valid inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it by wrapping the valid check in a `setTimeout` but would gladly hear a better way to do it.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.form.valid) {
        // submit
    }
});
```